# Let $E$ be Banach, $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly on a locally compact $X$, and $f \in C_b(X, E)$. Does $\int f\mathrm d\mu_n\to\int f\mathrm d\mu$ in norm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space
- $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all finite **signed** Borel measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ be the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $X$, and
- $\mathcal C_0(X)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ that vanish at infinity.

We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ is a Banach space. Let $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$. We define weak convergence by
$$
\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_b(X),
$$
and weak$^*$ convergence by
$$
\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu \overset{\text{def}}{\iff} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall f \in \mathcal C_0 (X).
$$

Previously, I proved that

> [Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568181/let-mu-n-rightharpoonup-mu-on-a-compact-x-if-e-is-banach-and-fx-to-e) Let $f:X \to E$ be continuous bounded and $\mu_n,\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$. If $X$ is compact and $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$, then
> $$
> \int_X f \mathrm d \mu_n \to \int_X f \mathrm d \mu \quad \text{in} \quad |\cdot|.
> $$

I would like to ask if we can generalize above result in the following directions, i.e.,

1. Replace the compactness of $X$ by local compactness (and possibly separability).
2. Replace $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ by $\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$.

I feel that 2. maybe not possible because in the previous proof, I used the fact that $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ implies $\{[\mu_n] \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded. However, this is [not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479722/confusion-with-the-narrow-and-weak-convergence-of-measures?noredirect=1&lq=1) if $\mu_n \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

---

I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568187/let-e-be-banach-mu-n-to-mu-weakly-on-a-locally-compact-x-and-f-in-c-b) question on MSE, but it seems to get no answer. So I post it here.

Comment: I don't understand 1. You did not insist $X$ to be compact. If $X$ is compact, the function spaces all agree and it is not clear, what the question is. For point 2, let $X$ be the real line and $\mu_n$ the Lebesgue measure on the interval $[n,n+1]$ and zero elsewhere. Let $E$ be the complex numbers.

Comment: @Echo For 1., if $X$ is compact, then theorem holds. I would like to ask if it still holds in case $X$ is only locally compact (and possibly separable).